# Create input jack from tape head

Tags: audio

This is my first question on here as I'm tinkering with some audio devices, etc. My intention is to create an audio input jack

[image: jack]

from a dismantled audio tape head as seen on this picture:

[image: tape head]

So that with the end result you can do tape experiments [like these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwRf9rih2DI).

Now, I'm a real n00b when it comes to electricity etc., so I have no clue what cables from the tape head I should attach to which from an audio jack cable.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have three connections on the tape head, can't really see from the picture. You can use the continuity tester to check for the ground lead. This should be connected to the metal shield of the head, you can leave it unconnected. You'll want to connect the other two wires to your two inputs. Hope that helps.